# How to create "fluid" or "squishy" bacteria-like nodes in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, graphics, sprite-kit

I'm currently designing a game in **Swift** and **Spritekit** that calls for bacteria-like graphics for the main player. I have no idea how to approach the physics and visual effects of a node like this. If you don't know what I'm talking about, here's a visual:

[image: Idk about you but I cant stop watching this]

So basically the player is a circle/oval that can completely alter it's shape based on the surrounding structures.

I've tried this by creating a huge array of nodes strung together to create the larger structure, however this is extremely inefficient and lags the computer when I try to scale it up to multiple players. I also want to fudge this the least amount as possible since it requires realistic (or at least expected) physics of something like this with the ability to jump, move, slide, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this could help (I haven't tried it by myself) https://github.com/kevinhartman/LiquidKit

Comment: @Whirlwind thanks but that looks like it doesn't support the physics ability to jump, move as a singular unit, etc.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I’m looking at doing something similar.

Comment: @NeilFaulkner sadly no. Im sure there’s something out there though.